# How can I organize my div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm having a bit of a problem with my div tags ( fiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQLq/).

What I want to accomplish is this:

When you click on the left image, the entire div tag (app1) should move to the left and fade out. Also the div tag behind that (app2), should FADE IN.

When I had them the same size, it would work as so. But when I made them different sizes, this is the problem I have (again, check my fiddle for visual demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQLq/).

I WANT them to be different sizes. Have the front one fade out, and the one behind to fade in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Forget Me Not</title>

<style>

body
{
background-color:#66d9ff;
}

#app1{
position:absolute;
width:250px;
height:250px;
z-index:1;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
background:white;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
text-align:center
}

#app2{
position:absolute;
width:300px;
height:300px;
z-index:0;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
background:white;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
text-align:center;
}

img.appIMG1{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #888888;
}

img.appIMG2{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #888888;
}

</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".appIMG1").click(function () {
        $("#app1").animate({
            left: '250px',
            opacity: 0
        });
    $("#app2").fadeIn("slow");
       });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="app1"><p><b><u><font face="TimeBurner" color="#66d9ff" size="6">Do you want to make a reminder?</b></u></font></p>
<br>
<img class="appIMG1" border="0" src="YES.png" align="left" hspace=1.8% >
<img class="appIMG2" border="0" src="NO.png" align="right" hspace=2%>
</div>

<div id="app2">
<form>
Name for the reminder: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
On what days would you like to be reminded on: <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="Monday">Monday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="Tuesday">Tuesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="Wednesday">Wednesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="Thursday">Thursday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="Friday">Friday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="Saturday">Saturday<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want your `app2` div to not display originally and then fade in. Is that correct? Set it in the markup as:

```
<div id="app2" style="display:none">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQLq/1/)

Comment: @Ebadly Also could you accept this as the answer when you have the chance?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the one behind to be hidden until you click the front one, it's as easy as adding `display: none;` to the CSS for `#app2`.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/4ZQLq/2/

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of good CSS practice, I recommend placing common CSS tasks like this into helper classes for easy reuse:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

It makes for smaller CSS classes in general and increases HTML code readability since you have less clutter and common functions can be given friendly names. Remember that you can add more than one class to your HTML and with good class names, they can become very descriptive.

I've redone the previous two answers with some new CSS, which allows for:

The removal of the <b><u> tags, which are now handled by CSS. The removal of the hspace attribute on the <img> tags, which is deprecated and no longer supported in HTML5. Also, many of the HTML attribute tags that modify presentation are now handled by CSS and are reusable across other pages if you choose.

After all this, the HTML before the form is (in my opinion) much easier to read and looks like this:

```
<body>
<!-- php stuff goes the body -->
<div id="app1"><p class="reminderFont">Do you want to make a reminder?</p>
<br>
<img class="appIMG1 floatLeft" src="YES.png">
<img class="appIMG2 floatRight" src="NO.png">
</div>

<div id="app2" class="hidden">
```

Managing your HTML's appearance with CSS will make your life easier in the long run, makes code easier to read, and is becoming the web standard as certain HTML presentation attributes like hspace are removed. I hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/VPcJs/3/